# How to change bitronix jms pool parameters?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.0.RC1 + bitronix + hornetq (embedded) + JPA, and I'd like to increase bitronix jmsConnectionFactory pool size, currently it's limited at 10. Is there a simple way to do it, inside application.properties for example or inside a @Configuration class?

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure it via `application.properties` at the moment (I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2027)), but you can do it from a `@Configuration` class by declaring your own `XAConnectionFactoryWrapper` bean:

```java
@Bean
public XAConnectionFactoryWrapper xaConnectionFactoryWrapper() {
    return new XAConnectionFactoryWrapper() {
        @Override
        public ConnectionFactory wrapConnectionFactory(
                XAConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            PoolingConnectionFactoryBean pool = new PoolingConnectionFactoryBean();
            pool.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            pool.setMaxPoolSize(50);
            return pool;
        }

    };
}
```